# How to add 2D np array to front of 3D np array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D `numpy` array and I want to add a 2D np array of 0's to the front of it.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros(3,3,3)
for i in np.arange(0,2):
    for j in np.arange(0,2):
        for k in np.arange(0,2):
            A[i,j,k] = 10
print(A)
#returns:
 [[[10. 10.  0.]
  [10. 10.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[10. 10.  0.]
  [10. 10.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]]
```

I want to add another array B so that:

```
B = np.zeros(3,3)
print(B)
#returns 
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]

# add B to front of A 
# B + A = 
[[[0.  0.  0.]
  [0.  0.  0.]
  [0.  0.  0.]]

 [[10. 10.  0.]
  [10. 10.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[10. 10.  0.]
  [10. 10.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]]
```

I've tried np.append(B,A) but it returns a 2D array.

Comment: Read all of np.append docs before trying to use it. `B` should be 3d, e.g. (1,3,3), and you need to specify axis=0.

Comment: ah. I had ```B``` 3d but not axis=0. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `numpy.vstack` and by reshaping your array. For instance:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((3, 3, 3))
b = np.zeros((3, 3))
res = np.vstack((b.reshape(1, 3, 3), a))
```

By the way, you can create your array `A` more efficiently:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((3,3,3))
A[:2, :2, :2] = 10
```